# WPF Prism Loading views to Region, previous view is not removed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism

I'm new to WPF Prism, my problem is this.

1. I have a region and I register a view like this

   ```
   _container.RegisterType(typeof(Object), typeof(MgpOptions),typeof(MgpOptions).FullName);

   _container.RegisterType(typeof(Object), typeof(SgpOptions), typeof(SgpOptions).FullName);
   ```
2. Then I navigate to it like this

   ```
   _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.AppBarRegion].NavigationService.RequestNavigate(typeof(MgpOptions).FullName);`
   ```
3. On sum button click event I navigate to SgOptions View like this

   ```
   _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.AppBarRegion].RequestNavigate(typeof(SgpOptions).FullName);
   ```

My problem is when the 3rd step completed both views appear in the region 
I just want to show one View at a time.

Comment: i think your view or view model needs to implement IRegionMemberLifetime and implement KeepAlive in order to remove from region when navigating.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following as **Prism's Regions** work differently depending on the control they are being adapted to:

- If you are using an **ItemsControl**, you have an **AllActiveRegion** region type, which basically is a region that never deactivates its views, and therefore, all its views will be considered *active*. In such scenario, navigating to another view will not *deactivate* the previous one.

Instead, you need to configure the region as **SingleActiveRegion** by using **ContentControl**. This type of region allows only one view to be active at the same time. So when navigating the previous view will indeed get *deactivated*.

You can find more information related here at [Prism Region Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#sec7) section.